# Pex - testing 'Type' parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, pex

I have a couple of methods that check for assignablity or interface assignabilty between types.  Therefore I have signatures like `(Type type1, Type type2)`.

Pex struggles to generate inputs for these parameters and ends up with some type build something or other type (sorry closed VS already) because `Type` itself is abstract.

I tried creating a factory that would pick one of four test 'types' based on inputs and then hoped that Pex would work the factory out to generate different inputs, and therefore put different inputs into my test method.

- typeof(object) and typeof(object)
- typeof(object) and typeof(string)
- and so on...

Now it just complains that Sytem.Type is abstract and can't be explored.  I'm new to Pex, but I don't know how else to generate varying inputs for the methods.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an int as input and use a switch to choose a type based on the int value. A nasty hack, but sometimes required with Pex.

Comment: I think you're right - it doesn't feel great, but it's a simple solution to something which is probably going to be far more difficult to 'correctly' sort out in the long run.

Comment: There is no correct solution, AFAIK. Pex inputs are really unusable for anything complex. Alas.